# Nginx. Laravel. How to set up multiple endpoints in subfolders

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, nginx-location

I have such a project structure

`<root>/public/laravel_app/index.php  — Laravel index file`

`<root>/public/index.php              — CraftCMS index file`

I want to load *CraftCMS* app at

`https://<domain>`

and *Laravel* app at `https://<domain>/laravel_app`

Here is my `vhost.conf`

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    index index.php index.html;

    root /var/www/public;

    ssl_certificate       /var/www/docker/certs/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /var/www/docker/certs/nginx.key;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

I've looked through almost all related SO questions and have tried a lot of stuff, so, if it's possible, please, send suggestions related to my config.

I'm not a sysadmin and I am an Apache user (there it works in such a way without any tweaking), so I apologize, if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Is url rewriting for your CraftCMS working perfectly? So that only Laravel url rewriting is broken. Or neither both are works?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra

It's not loading Laravel. I can't get that endpoint. nginx is passing everything through the `<root>/public/index.php`.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra or I can make working Laravel by changing the `root /var/www/public;` to `root /var/www/public/laravel_app;`, but I **can't make working both**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make 2 url rewriting I think, because `laravel_app` has it's own `index.php` for rewrite.

```
server {
    ...

    root /var/www/public;

    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /laravel_app {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /laravel_app/index.php?$args;
    }

    ...
}
```

Hope this works

Comment: Hallelujah!! Thanks a lot)

Comment: If I can help you somehow, feel free to ask)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}
```

to

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Adding the `$uri/` tells nginx to look for a directory with the uri name.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. It's showing to me a *CraftCMS* error page, so it's loading `<root>/public/index.php`